# How do I get PayPal transaction and fixed rate fees?

Tags: android, paypal

I'm teaching myself how to make android apps and I was wondering how do I get the transaction and fixed rate fees?

From my understanding I would use the PayPal APIs if I wanted to "integrate" PayPal into my app, but all I want is the transaction and fixed rate values (nothing about accounts, sales, etc).

For example in here [Transaction Fee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onGHC.png) it shows 2.7% transaction fee inside the US and 4.2% outside. And here [Fixed Fee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXiI3.png) it shows 0.30 AUD for the fixed fee. Is it possible for me to get the percentages and values from the API or will I have to manually set the values in my app?

If it's possible please explain step by step how I would do this, so I can better understand. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to pull the fee from the API response (where available) or via [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) / [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/) depending on whether you're using Classic APIs or REST.

Comment: If I did that wouldn't it pull the fee for a particular transaction (the total transaction fee) instead of the percentage?

Comment: Yes, which is what people typically want...the actual amount.  If you're looking for the actual percentage, simply subtract .30 from the fee amount and then do the math to figure the percentage of the fee in relation to the transaction amount.  This will be more accurate than doing the math on your end and hoping it matches the actual fee.